# VBScript to return dates older than today by one day only

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below SQL query that return dates, I need to evaluate the dates and result only dates older than today by one day only.

```
SELECT Address,
       max(Date+ ' ' + time)as last_Trans_time 
FROM AxA_Transactions 
where address is not null 
GROUP BY Address
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL 2008

Comment: Just use the query you have as a view and add a where clause, which checks if truncated last_trans_time is equal to truncated sysdate + 1.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ms sql, but it should be something like: SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT address,
               MAX(date) as last_trans_time 
          FROM AxA_Transactions 
         WHERE address IS NOT NULL 
         GROUP BY address) addr
 WHERE addr.last_trans_time = DATEADD(day, 1, CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME()));

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly (especially the part around exactly what "only dates older than today by one day only" means), I believe this should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT [Address],
           MAX([Date] + ' ' + [time]) AS last_Trans_time 
    FROM AxA_Transactions 
    WHERE [Address] IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY [Address]
) info
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, info.last_Trans_time) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE() - 1)
```